# AnkhSVN issue with hidden files when pulling files that were recently added to the codebase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ankhsvn, hidden-files

So I'm working on a project, and we got the repository set up, and we have a working base, but every time a file gets added to the project and committed, whenever someone tries to update that file doesn't show up, and you actually have to go into the solution explorer to show all files, and the new files are hidden and have to be added to the project. Is there a way to change this, or is this just the way that AnkhSVN works?

Using VS2012, C#, MVC5. Particularly the files in the model's folder won't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files included in a project are defined in the project ".csproj" file. So, when adding some files to a project you must be sure to also include the modifications in this file in your repository.